# causative, passive, causative-passive

Tags: passive-voice, causation

I have been studying the causative, passive, causative-passive forms and found that they are very confusing. I am not confused much about the conjugation (される, etc), but in identifying the who/what the subject is and what he is doing (or what is being done by who).

Anyone who also have this confusion? Please point me to resources where I can practice (for a workbook/drill kind) or examples that can be of great reference.

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14936/22352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Genki II Textbook*** (Although not *technically* free) is a great resource.

```
I am not confused much about the conjugation (される, etc),

but in identifying the who/what the subject is and what he is doing

(or what is being done by who).
```

(Almost everything down below is from Genki II)

Here's a way to remember it.

---

**Causative**

> **先生** は **学生** に　会話を**覚えさせました**。
>
> (**"Director"**) は (**"Cast")** に (**"Action"**).
>
> *The professor made the students memorize the dialogue.*

**The "director" decides what is allowed and what is to be done.** Marked with は or が.

**The "cast" performs the action.** Usually goes with に.

**The "action"** is described with a causative form of the verb.

---

**Passive**

> **私**　は　**友達** に　車を使われました。
>
> (**"Victim"**) は (**"Villain"**) に (**"Evil Act"**).
>
> *I had my car used by my friend.*

In *most* passive sentences, the "victim" has been unfavorably affected by the "villain's" act.

**The one doing the action is the "villain", and the "victim" is affected in some way or another.**

Here is an example where I think it is "not unfavorable", however the "victim" will still be affected.

> このパッケージ**に**は、あらゆるもの**が**含まれている。
>
> Everything is included in this package. 
>   ("Everything" is "being included" by "the package".)

In this case, "Everything", or あらゆるもの, is the "victim", who is *being affected* by "being included".

"The package", or パッケージ, is the "villain" who is *including* "everything."

The reason why I don't consider this an "unfavorable" situation is because the sentence is about *inanimate objects*.

---

**Causative-Passive**

> **私**　は　**彼女**　に　**車を洗わされました**。
>
> (**"Puppet"**) は　(**"Puppet Master"**) に　(**"Action"**).
>
> My girlfriend made me wash her car.

**The "puppet" (i.e. 私 or "me"）is forced into performing an action.** Marked with は or が.

**The "puppet master" （i.e. 彼女 or "My girlfriend"）"wields power over, and manipulates", the "puppet".** Uses に.

The **"action" forced upon the "puppet"** is described with a causative-passive verb.

Comment: I'm curious about the word "tricked" in the English translation of the last example. I think that has a nuance which is not necessarily carried by　洗わされる. Perhaps "My girlfriend made me wash her car" is a better translation. Anyone agree/disagree?

Comment: @Locksleyu agree. I will change it because although the book gives that translation, it can lead to confusion. Thanks!

Comment: @Locksleyu I'm probably beating a dead horse here, but I also agree that the 'tricked' translation is suspect.  If I were to say `my girlfriend tricked me into washing her car`, I'd personally say something to the effect of: `私が彼女の車を洗うよう、彼女に騙{だま}された。`  Maybe not the most natural translation, but I would definitely use 騙される。